# Accurate roots of negative numbers in Python

Tags: python, complex-numbers, symbolic-math

I'm looking for a way to accurately compute roots of negative numbers in Python. I believe that **the inaccuracies I see are related to floating point**, but it seems like there should be a way to get the right answer for something as simple as this:

```
>>(-1+0j)**0.1
(0.9510565162951535+0.3090169943749474j)
```

**The answer I expect** in this case is `(0+1j)`. Though raising Python's response to the tenth does come close to -1, I am looking for an answer obtained from a more precise method, i.e., one that when raised to the tenth equals exactly -1, not a number really close to -1.

Is there a way to do this correctly with either a native Python library, or sympy/numpy/scipy etc?

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* tenth root of a complex number. Python has given you *a* tenth root, up to the limits of floating-point representation. How do you want to specify which root you want to get?

Comment: It's worth noting that `0.1` is impossible to represent exactly in floating point. Try `sum(0.1 for _ in range(8))` for an example of the rounding errors it can lead to.

Comment: @user2357112 It would be good to get all of them, and it would be ideal to avoid dealing with floating-point if I can. This is why I mention sympy - I'd rather get symbolic answers in terms of integers and i than floating point.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, I'm aware of this limitation. I feel it should be avoidable entirely; perhaps it was confusing that I mentioned looking into the Decimal library, as it doesn't seem to address the problem of accuracy much at all.

Answer (score 1):

-1 has not one but 10 complex tenth roots. You got only one of them. If `a` is your returned root, `a ** 5` is also a root:

> (a ** 5) ** 10 = (a ** 10) ** 5 = (-1) ** 5 = -1

But if you run:

```
a = (-1 + 0j) ** 0.1
print(a)
print(a ** 5)
```

you'll get:

```
(0.951056516295+0.309016994375j)
(1.11022302463e-16+1j)
```

You see `a ** 5` is very close to `1j`.